# HTML & CSS - scaling background to fit mobile screen

Tags: android, html, css

I'm having problems with background image fitting my Xperia Z1 screen and I have no idea how to do that correctly.

```
body
{
  background-image: url('bg.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;       
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

This is my current CSS code. Background image should customize its resolution according to screen resolution.

Desktop screenshot:

[image]

Mobile screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try to use `vh` and `vw` instead of percentage value .

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that using `@media (max-width: 500px;)` and type changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your head tag to define a mobile viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```